# Awesome window manager keybinding executes but also fall-through to the focused client

Tags: linux, window-manager, awesome

I have a key binding `Super + Menu`. Like this:

```
awful.key({ modkey,        }, "Menu", function (c) c:kill() end,
              {description = "Close", group = "client"}),
```

After it is pressed it does what it should *but* also sends the `Menu` key press to the current client in focus. I do **NOT** want `Menu` key press to be sent to the current client in focus. Only execute the key binding. One key press should only translate to one action. Not two. How can I do it? Thank you.